# Transferable Crew in World of Tanks

Tags: world-of-tanks

World of tanks allows some crews to be transferred to other tanks without losing the crew skill %, for example Stug to E25. Is there alist of tank crews that can be transferred? Tried looking at the WoT wiki but couldn't find any.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens if you put a different tank's crew in your new tank?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20084/what-happens-if-you-put-a-different-tanks-crew-in-your-new-tank)

Comment: No, that question is about what happens when you move crew. My question is about how to find out compatible crews. i.e crew transfer without any penalty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one case where there is no penalty - a premium tank can hold crews of tanks of the same type (light, medium, heavy, TD, arty) and, of course, of the same nation.

So a premium German heavy tank can take on crew trained on any other German heavy tank without penalty. That's it. Not the other way around, not in any other way - all other combinations will have some penalties until you retrain the crew and lose their compatibility with the previous tank.

Note that this means that you shouldn't ever have a crew trained for a premium tank - choose any non-premium tank of the same type, retrain the crew for it, and then this crew will be able to do well in two of your tanks.

Comment: No penalty if I move the crew back to the non-premium vehicle? (move from premium to non-premium where the crew was initially trained)

Comment: @user3596588 The key point is to not retrain them - if the team qualification is for Stug, then they'll be a 'Stug-team' unless/until you retrain them for the new tank. A 'Stug-team' can function w/o penalties in a Stug and E25, but an 'E25-team' will have penalties if put in a Stug.

Comment: @RAnand the premium tank effectively counts as any other tank of the same class and nation. So a KV220 can take the crew of a KV1 or IS6 and get them both experience (or mix them into that KV220), but it can't take the crew of a DW.20 or T1 Heavy at all, and it can't take the crew of a BT7 or T34 without penalty/retraining.

Answer (score 1):

The list of [Bonuses and penalties](http://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Crew#Bonuses_and_Penalties) clearly answer your question

> The amount of this Penalty is variable depending upon whether his Vehicle Competence and the vehicle he moved to are vehicles of the same "Type" (ie TD, MT, LT, HT, or SPG) or are premium vehicles. The Penalty incurred is according to the following situations:

- If a crew member is moved to a vehicle of the same Type as that in
  which he has his Vehicle Competence, and the vehicle is a premium
  vehicle, there is no penalty.
- If a crew member is in a vehicle of the same Type as that in which he
  has his Vehicle Competence, and the vehicle is not a premium vehicle,
  he will take a 25% penalty to his current Training Level. For
  example, an 80% Training Level will be reduced by 25% to 60% and a
  100% level would be reduced to 75%.
- If a crew member is in a vehicle of a different Type as that in which
  he has his Vehicle Competence, and the vehicle is a premium vehicle,
  he would also take a 25% Penalty to his current Training Level.
- If a crew member is in a vehicle of a different Type as that in which
  he has his Vehicle Competence, and the vehicle is not a premium
  vehicle, he will take a 50% penalty to his current Training Level.
  For example, an 80% Training Level will be reduced by 50% to 40%,
  while a 100% level would be reduced to 50%.

> Vehicle Competence Penalty on Experience to Increase Training Level: A tanker crewing a vehicle that he is has no Vehicle Competence in will earn less experience from each battle to be applied to increasing his Training Level.

- In a new vehicle of the same Type as that in which he has his Vehicle
  Competence, there is no Penalty if the new vehicle is a premium
  vehicle.
- In a vehicle of a different Type as that in which he has his Vehicle
  Competence, the crew member would earn 50% less experience per battle
  if the new vehicle is a premium vehicle.
- In a new non-premium vehicle of the same Type as that in which he has
  his Vehicle Competence, a Penalty will apply and the crewman would
  earn 50% less experience per battle than he normally would.
- In a new non-premium vehicle of a different Type as that in which he
  has his Vehicle Competence, a Penalty will apply and the crewman
  would earn 75% less experience per battle than he normally would.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a crew for the same class of tank (heavy, light etc) in a premium vehicle of that type without a skill penalty applying.

*eg. I can use my Churchill 1 (standard heavy) crew in my TOG (premium heavy) and they will still function at 100% skill*

You **can not** use a crew for a premium tank in a non-premium tank without a penalty, even if they are the same class of tank.

*eg. If I trained a crew to 100% in my Dicker Max (premium TD), they will function at 75% if I swap them into my Nashorn.*

You can not use a crew for a different class of tank in a premium tank without a penalty.

*eg. If I trained a M3 Less (standard medium) crew to 100% and used then in my T14 (premium heavy), they would still have a skill penalty.  I don't know what this is, but I think its pretty severe, like 50% or 60% effectiveness.*

So one way to powerlevel crews is to have more than one premium tank of the same class, and a normal tank of that class.  You play a round in the normal one, and swap the crew to each premium, that way you can get multiple X2, X3 etc XP bonuses for the same crew.

*eg. I can play the same crew (give or take a member) in my Churchill 1, TOG II and Excelsior and get three daily doubles.  Because the TOG and Excelsior are both premium heavies I can use the same crew in them without penalty.  This is great when WG run x5 XP weekends :D*

I hope this helps!